# Is there a more efficient way to find all cloudtrail events in AWS performed by a specific role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I need to analyse all cloudtrail events within an account (actually multiple accounts, but restricting it to one for now) - however I don't have direct access to the S3 bucket where events are stored.

I need to find all events initiated by any role that fits a pattern. The reason for this is that I need to calculate the guard duty costs associated with the application that is making the API calls.

I have a script which works (it's just thrown together at the moment), however it's VERY slow as it's analysing millions of cloudtrail events.

Is there a better way to get the data I need?

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import json

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='<profile_name_here>')
client = session.client('cloudtrail')

total_events = 0
target_events = 0
start_time = datetime(2020, 1, 22)
guard_duty_cost = 0.0000044

paginator = client.get_paginator('lookup_events')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    StartTime = start_time,
    MaxResults = 1000
)

y = 1

for response in response_iterator:
    events = response['Events']
    print('Processing response {}'.format(y))
    y += 1
    for event in events:
        total_events += 1
        cloudtrail_event = event['CloudTrailEvent']
        cloudtrail_event_json = json.loads(cloudtrail_event)
        user_identity = cloudtrail_event_json['userIdentity']
        if 'sessionContext' in user_identity:
            user_name = user_identity['sessionContext']['sessionIssuer']['userName']
            if '<target_role_pattern>' in user_name:
                target_events += 1       

total_cost = guard_duty_cost * total_events
target_cost = guard_duty_cost * target_events

print('Total number of events since {} is {} - cost EUR {}'.format(start_time, total_events, total_cost))
print('Number of target events since {} is {} - cost EUR {}'.format(start_time, target_events, target_cost))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider using AWS Athena for this - but you will need access to the S3 bucket - not sure how any solution is going to work without that access.

> Using Athena with CloudTrail logs is a powerful way to enhance your
>   analysis of AWS service activity. For example, you can use queries to
>   identify trends and further isolate activity by attributes, such as
>   source IP address or user.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html

Comment: Yeah this is my main other thought - the solution outlined above works without this access as it is accessing cloudtrail directly, but Athena is high on my list of other approaches - I'm trying to get access to the bucket at the moment to test this approach.